# ¿Cómo tener un scheduler asíncrono y no concurrente en Spring?

Tags: java, spring, async

Tengo en la clase principal que inicia la app:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAsync
public class ExperianRequestBotApplication extends RefApplication {

    public ExperianRequestBotApplication() throws RefException {
        super();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RefException {
        try {
            new ExperianRequestBotApplication().start(args);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(" ------- OFFLINE ------- ");
            System.out.println("La aplicación no esta disponible por :" + e);
        }

    }
}
```

y un scheduler

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTaskSincronizarContactos {

    @Autowired
    private ExperianRequestBotService experianRequestBotService;

    private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTaskSincronizarContactos.class);

    // Método Shedule encargado de sincronizar los usuarios modificados con Experian 
    @Async
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */15 * ? * *")
    public void SincronizarContactos() throws Exception {
```

Quiero evitar el scheduler se vuelva a lanzar si el proceso interno tarda más de los 15 minutos en los que se vuelve a iniciar la tarea.

No encuentro la manera. He probado implementando @DisallowConcurrentExecution con la librería de quartz pero sigue siendo concurrente.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 1):

Dado que lo que buscas es un control simple de un proceso para decidir si se ejecutara o no, la solución mas simple es que crees una clase que sirva de `Semaforo` que se encargue de llevar el estado de la ejecución, ten mucho cuidado de garantizar la ejecución del método `stop()` para evitar que los procesos se atasquen porque no hubo un cambio de estado, he realizado un ejemplo que se ejecuta cada segundo y muestra que procesos se ejecutan y cuales se omiten.

```
public class EjecucionController {
    private static boolean isRunning;

    public synchronized static void start() {
        isRunning = true;
    }

    public synchronized static void stop() {
        isRunning = false;
    }

    public synchronized static boolean isRunning() {
        return isRunning;
    }
}

@Component
public class ScheduledTaskSincronizarContactos {

    @Scheduled(cron = "*/1 * * ? * *")
    @Async
    public void sincronizarContactos () {
        // Generamos un id para verificar cual proceso se ejecuta y cual se omite
        Random random = new Random();
        int id = random.nextInt(100000);

        // Utilizamos la clase semáforo para verificar si hay otro proceso en ejecución
        if (!SemaforoController.isRunning()) {
            try {
            // Iniciamos el semáforo  para detener otras ejecuciones
            SemaforoController.start();

            System.out.println("Iniciando sincronización con ID: " + id);

                Thread.sleep(7000);
                System.out.println("Sincronización con ID: " + id + " Finalizada");
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally {
                // Garantizamos liberar el semaforo, muy importante para no detener otras ejecuciones
                // en caso de error.
                SemaforoController.stop();
            }
        }else {
            System.out.println("Sincronización omitida ID: " + id);
        }

    }
}
```

Para manejos mas avanzados java cuenta con la clase `Semaphore` que permite un control más avanzado.

Comment: Gracias por su respuesta, al final hemos decidido hacerlo con Quartz y no utilizar los scheduler de Srping. Las etiquetas DisallowConcurrentExecution Y PersistJobDataAfterExecution permiten que haya jobs asincronos y no concurrentes. Un saludo